# Pass value between tables with condition MySql

Tags: mysql

Im looking to make work this statement in MySql, I need to pass the value from table domains column webId only if this value is different than 0, and if so, I need it to copy this value into table customers column referwebId. The below code is giving me error: Unknown table 'domains' in field list.. 
What is wrong?
Thank you

```
BEGIN

if domains.webId NOT LIKE '0' then
insert into customers (referWebId) select
webId from domains;

END IF;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this

```
insert into customers (referWebId) 
select webId from domains
where webId NOT LIKE '0';
```

Per your posted code you can't simply check like that way

```
if domains.webId NOT LIKE '0' then
```

Rather use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)  like below

```
insert into customers (referWebId) 
select webId from domains where webId NOT LIKE '0'
on duplicate key update referWebId = values(referWebId);
```

Comment: can you please let me know the full correct code pls? if I put if not exists directly then its giving me error.. thank you

Comment: Hi Rahul, thank you, Im getting this error now:Can't update table 'customers' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Comment: Error exactly telling you the reason that: table you are trying to update is already have a open transaction (so locked). Moeover, that's altogether a separate question. Post it as separate quesion.